# How to avoid entering values in tables that are just information tables asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a model Client:

```
 public class Client
{
    public int ClientID
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    [Required]
    public string compte
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
public int Restr_typeID
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
public virtual Restr_type1 Restr_type
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
```

And Restr_type is also a model:

```
 public int Restr_type1ID
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string restr1_name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public int ActifID
    {
        get;
        set;
    } 
public virtual Actif Actifs
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
```

My problem is when I add an instance of client in the Clients table, it add also a line in Restr_types table and Actifs table. But this two tables are just information tables and therefore I want them to be static. What I want is only to stock a Client.

Can you help me please ?

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how EF works if you have an unattached object as a virtual property.

Basically if you create a new instance of `Client` and populate the `Restr_type` property with a reference that isn't an object that you got from EF, then it will treat the `Restr_type` property as having a new value so will add it to the DB and add a reference to that.

What you would want to do is use EF to query the database for `Restr_type` and use the reference returned from that. Otherwise just populate the `Restr_typeID` prop and leave the  `Restr_type` prop as null when you call `Add()` on your context.

I hope that makes sense. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592676.aspx this may help you understand the EF context a bit better

Comment: Thanks but I don't understand very well, do I have to discard the virtual property for Restr_type ?

Comment: No. I just assume you're getting this problem when calling .Add with entity framework, which means the object you are adding should have Restr_type set to null to prevent EF from considering it as a new value and adding a new row to the table. If you want to set the foreign key you should just set the Restr_typeID property but leave Restr_type null. Restr_type should be left in your entity though as when you do a select it will be populated.

Comment: Ok but how can I set it to null and using it for the form ? You mean in the model public virtual Restr_type restr_type have to be null ?   I am sorry it is not clear to me, I am a beginner can you explain a bit more thank you very much

Comment: EF has a concept of a "context cache" which keeps values attached to it that it then observes to see what changes to make when you Add/Update a value in the DB. What is happening is you are likely setting the value of Restr_type without it being in the EF context,so EF picks it up as a change to the DB. So as soon as you call Update or Add it is going to commit this change by adding a new row to the Restr_type table. To get around this you would either have this property set to null when a DB operation is performed. Otherwise you would need to call DbContext.Attach method and attach the ref

Comment: Once the reference to Restr_type is attached to the DbContext, EF will realise that this value is not a new value and when you call Update or Add it will just use the existing value to reference to.

Comment: ok it is more clear so if I understand well, I have to attach Restr_type to the DBcontext and automatically it will be in unchanged state ?